# How can I add buttons REMOVE and EDIT to my table?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

It is my teacher table in `index.html` which displayed only after click on button `Teachers` :

```
 <div class="container">
    <table class="teacherTable" border="1" width="100%" cellpadding="5">
        <thead>
        <th>TEACHER ID</th>
        <th>TEACHER NAME</th>
        <th>TEACHER POSITION</th>

        <tbody id="teacherBody">

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

because I have in my styles :

```
<style>
    .container table {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

And here is my `getTeachers.js` file :

```
GET: $(document).ready(
function () {

    // GET REQUEST
    $("#getAllTeachers").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        ajaxGet();
    });

    // DO GET
    function ajaxGet() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "checkTeachers",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.status == "success") {
                    var custList = "";
                    $.each(result.data,
                        function (i, teacher) {

                            var Html = "<tr>" +
                                "<td>" + teacher.teacherId + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + teacher.teacherName + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + teacher.position + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + 'X' + "</td>" +
                                "</tr>";
                            console.log("Teacher checking: ", teacher);
                            $('#teacherBody').append(Html);
                            $('#groupBody').empty();
                            $('.groupTable').hide();
                            $('.teacherTable').show();

                        });
                    console.log("Success: ", result);
                } else {
                    console.log("Fail: ", result);
                }
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log("ERROR: ", e);
            }
        });
    }
})
```

And also in `index.html` I have this button for looking for all teachers in my database :

```
   <button id="getAllTeachers" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Teachers</button>
```

So, my question is how to add one more or two fields to my table which should be called `REMOVE` and `EDIT`.

I saw some solutions but I have no idea how to use it with my `js` file.

Maybe I can use bootstrap for it or do it manually..

Answer (score 0):

Created a snippet to show you a possible way to solve the question. I used a "placeholder API" to simulate your code (so there's no "position", instead I used `username`).

The `edit` function is just mocked here - that can have so many possible directions, that I didn't want to elaborate the function.

```js
// fetching the data from the API
const fetchAllTeachers = async() => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    const json = await response.json()
    return json
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
    return []
  }
}

// data array for teachers
let teachers = []

// table row "template"
const tableRowHTML = (teacher) => {
  const {
    id,
    name,
    username
  } = teacher // this is source-dependent
  let html = ''
  html += `<tr>`
  html += `<td>${ id }</td>`
  html += `<td>${ name }</td>`
  html += `<td>${ username }</td>`
  html += `<td><button data-editid="${ id }">EDIT</button></td>`
  html += `<td><button data-removeid="${ id }">REMOVE</button></td>`
  html += `</tr>`
  return html
}

// updating table
const updateTable = (teachers) => {
  const tableBody = jQuery('#teacherBody')
  let html = ''
  teachers.forEach(teacher => {
    html += tableRowHTML(teacher)
  })
  tableBody.html(html)
}

// jQuery action bindings
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#fetchAllTeachers').on('click', async function() {
    teachers = await fetchAllTeachers()
    updateTable(teachers)
  })

  $('body').on('click', '[data-removeid]', function() {
    teachers = removeTeacher(this.getAttribute('data-removeid'), teachers)
    updateTable(teachers)
  })

  $('body').on('click', '[data-editid]', function() {
    teachers = editTeacher(this.getAttribute('data-editid'), teachers)
    updateTable(teachers)
  })
})


// remove action
const removeTeacher = (id, teachers) => {
  const teacher = teachers.find(({
    id: tId
  }) => tId == id)
  let ret = [...teachers]
  if (ret.indexOf(teacher) !== -1) {
    ret.splice(teachers.indexOf(teacher), 1);
  }
  return ret
}

// edit action
const editTeacher = (id, teachers) => {
  let ret = [...teachers]
  console.log('create the edit feature; teacher ID:', id)
  return ret
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.container table {
  /*display: none;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button id="fetchAllTeachers">GET ALL TEACHERS</button>
  <table class="teacherTable" border="1" width="100%" cellpadding="5">
    <thead>
      <th>TEACHER ID</th>
      <th>TEACHER NAME</th>
      <th>TEACHER POSITION</th>
      <th colspan="2"></th>
      <tbody id="teacherBody"></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```